# Generalisation of bisection theorem

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

The Bisection Theorem says that, given two regions in the plane, there exists a line separating them into equal size respectively. This result has a generalization in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, which can be proved by Borsuk Ulam Theorem.

I want to know whether this can be generalized to surfaces of not constant curvature zero. For example, given two regions in hyperbolic paraboloid surface, does there exist a geodesic line that separates them into equal size respectively?

Comment: For the two-dimensional version, the ["rotating knife" argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem#Two-dimensional_variant:_proof_using_a_rotating-knife) should generalize directly.

Comment: Another search term would be Ham Sandwich Theorem.